# Как правильно предзагрузить изображения для использования three.js?

Tags: javascript, html5, разработка-игр, three.js

Привет, изучаю three.js. Хочу добавить на сцену большое количество объектов с одной текстурой. В цикле использую такой код:

```
var cube_geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(cellSize, cellSize, cellSize),
    cube_texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/texture.png'),
    cube_material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: cube_texture, transparent: true}),
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(cube_geometry, cube_material);
```

Как правильно предзагрузить изображения для дальнейшего использования?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Использовать TextureLoader

   ```
   cube_texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/texture.png');
   ```

   вместо cube_texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/texture.png');
2. Вынести переменную cube_texture за цикл, что бы она создавалась один раз

   ```
   var cube_texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/texture.png');

   for(var i = 0; i < your_counter; i++){
       var cube_geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(cellSize, cellSize, cellSize),
       cube_material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: cube_texture, transparent: true}),
       cube = new THREE.Mesh(cube_geometry, cube_material);
   }
   ```